Kotlin + SpringBoot Integration
I am new to Kotlin and developing a Spring Boot Project with Kotlin support. Following gradle configuration file I have for the same.
    plugins {
      kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.25"
      kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.25"
      id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
      id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    }

    group = "com.ktdemo"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    java {
       toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
      }
    }

    configurations {
       compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
      }
   }

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }

    dependencies {
       implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
       implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
       implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
       compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
       annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
       testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
       testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
       testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
     }

     kotlin {
        compilerOptions {
          freeCompilerArgs.addAll("-Xjsr305=strict")
        }
     }
    
     tasks.withType<Test> {
       useJUnitPlatform()
     }

However I am getting following error Plugin id:'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm',version:'1.9.25' was not found in any of the following sources.
Anyone has any solution to this?
